# show app lock pattern dialog when unlocking the phone

Tags: java, android

I have MainActivity and on its onResume method I call pattern lock to create and confirm user identity. User visits and leave this MainActivity back and forth while **active** on the app as well as when phone is in **sleep mode and user unlocks** it. These both scenarios will call onRestart, onStart and onResume methods, but I only want to revoke the pattern in unlock scenario.

handlePattern() method needs a proper distinguishing to be called.

How to distinguish this when I call the handlePattern method ?

MainActivity.class

```
onCreate(){}

onResume(){
   //help needed to know that user is just visiting activity in app back and forth
     or came back after unlocking the screen.
   if(isPatternCallRequired){
        handlePattern()
   }
}
```

Comment: any guidance on why downvoted ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onStop() method call you can check if the player is in sleep mode  and cache the boolean.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) 
_context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isInSleepMode = !pm.isScreenOn();
```

Check for the build version

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 20)
    // use isInteractive()
else
    // use isScreenOn()
```

in onRestart which will get called when you resume from sleep - based on the cached value you can show the pattern to unlock.

You may need to reset the cached value once you are done using it.

onResume may not be a right API for the call as it will be called even when your activity loads.

Edited answer based on your comment

Comment: hmm.. I see `isScreenOn` is depreciated and other methods like `powerManager.isInteractive();
        powerManager.isDeviceIdleMode()` requires api level 20 and I have to work with 16 only. Is there a better solution ?

Comment: You can always check for the build version in cases where you will need to support both. Until your target version is greater that 20, both the api's will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` too like this,

First, Register your Application in your Application class.

```
public class StackApp extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = StackApp.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String INTENT_ACTION_APP_STATE_CHANGE = "intent_action_app_state_change";
    public static final String INTENT_DATA_IS_IN_BACKGROUND = "intent_data_is_in_background";

    private static int mNumRunningActivities = 0;

    private static AtomicBoolean mIsAppInForeground = new AtomicBoolean();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {

            // registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks is supported only from the SDK version 14.
            registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
                    mNumRunningActivities++;

                    if (mNumRunningActivities == 1) {
                        notifyAppState(false);

                        Log.i(TAG, "APP IN FOREGROUND");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
                    mNumRunningActivities--;

                    if (mNumRunningActivities == 0) {

                        notifyAppState(true);


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * To notify App state whether its in ForeGround or in Background
     *
     * @param isInBackground
     */
    private void notifyAppState(boolean isInBackground) {
        if (isInBackground) {
            mIsAppInForeground.set(false);
        } else {
            mIsAppInForeground.set(true);
        }

        sendAppStateChangeBroadcast(isInBackground);
    }

    public static boolean isInForeground() {
        return mIsAppInForeground.get();
    }

    private void sendAppStateChangeBroadcast(boolean isInBackground) {

        Log.i(TAG, "sendAppStateChangeBroadcast - isInBackground : " + isInBackground);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(INTENT_ACTION_APP_STATE_CHANGE);

        intent.putExtra(INTENT_DATA_IS_IN_BACKGROUND, isInBackground);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}
```

And register the broadcast and listen whether the App is going background or foreground like this Sample Activity example

```
public class SampleMyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private OnAppStateReceiver mAppStateReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_my);

        mAppStateReceiver = new OnAppStateReceiver();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(StackApp.INTENT_ACTION_APP_STATE_CHANGE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mAppStateReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mAppStateReceiver != null) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mAppStateReceiver);
        }
    }

    private class OnAppStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(action) && StackApp.INTENT_ACTION_APP_STATE_CHANGE.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                boolean isGoingBackground = intent.getBooleanExtra(StackApp.INTENT_DATA_IS_IN_BACKGROUND, false);

                if (isGoingBackground) {
                    //Your app is not vissible to the use
                } else {
                    // App is visible to the user.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Note:  If you want to listen in Multiple Activity you can create a base
>   class and add the listener there and you can do the operation, In that
>   case you can reduce a lot of code.