# How to turn on screen in an Activity when the Activity was already opened?

Tags: android

I am not very good at English.^_^
There were many answers about turn on screen using

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

in `Activity.onCreate()`, it can really turning on the screen just when the activity is not launched before the screen is turned on. If the activity is launched before the screen is turned off, then I turn off the screen (the activity `onStop()` but not `onDestroy()`), then the activity receive any events make it have to turn on the screen again, how to implement this?

I try to put the `getWindow().addFlags(...)` in `onStart()` and `getWindow().clearFlags(...)` in `onStop()`, it's not always work, sometimes it work, sometimes it is not.

Finally, I use

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "VideoChat");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
```

in `onStart()`, and preserve the `getWindow().addFlags(...)` in `onCreate()`, I can really turn on the screen and show my activity in front of 'lock screen' when the screen is off and my activity is in the "`onStop()` state".

But, the `PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK` is deprecated in API level 17. My minimum API is 18，target API is 25. And the above method need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>`. All of this is not what I want.

Google said: "Most applications should use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON instead of this type of wake lock, as it will be correctly managed by the platform as the user moves between applications and doesn't require a special permission." But it was not give any idea about how to use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON to turn on the screen when the Activity was already launched.

So, is there any idea about how to turn on the screen and show an already launched activity without deprecated method?

Have I made myself clear?^_^

Illustrate:

Turn on screen --> Open Activity A --> Turn off screen --> A receive some event --> How to let A to turn on the screen and show itself in front of Lock Screen with not deprecated method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow up the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45617745/900128) answer, And when you get the event just check

```
StackApp.isInForeground()
```

If it returns false, in that case, check whether the screen is on or not. If it's in background, then check like this,

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

final boolean isScreenOn;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    isScreenOn = powerManager.isInteractive();
} else {
    isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn()
}
```

Based on the screen is on or off you can do the action.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not my question. I am not want to check the screen state. I just want to know how to turn on the screen programmatically from an activity, when the activity already open. In other word, the activity is already opened by the user, then the user turn off the screen, then how to turn on the screen and show the activity programmatically?

Comment: If the activity never opened, you can use `Intent` to start activity and use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON` and so on to turn on the screen, but when the activity already opened, those methods do not work.